# How to compare 2 tables in a worksheet in header level as well as in line level

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare line status between T1 and P1. I tried VLOOKUP. But using that I was able to compare only Header ID's. But using Header ID and Line ID, we need to compare Line status and Line event also:

[image]

Comment: How specifically do you want to compare them, and what do you want to do with that information?

Comment: OK, so what have you tried and where did you run into trouble? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Add helper columns that concatenate the fields you want to compare - you can hide that columns. Then use Vlookup on that helper columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a helper column for T1 and one for P1. Each of them to concatentate `Header ID`, `Line ID`, `Line Status` and `Line Event`. For example for T1 using the formula

```
=A:A & "-" & C:C & "-" & D:D & "-" & E:E
```

Then use a lookup or match function on those helper columns. If a match can be found they are the same. If no match is found either the corresponding pair of `Header ID` and `Line ID` does not exist or their `Line Status`/`Line Event` is different.

[image]

For comparison of the helper columns you cas use something like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F:F,N:N,0)),"different","same")
```

where `F` and `N` are the helper columns.

---

Of course this just tells you if lines exist that have the same `Header ID`, `Line ID`, `Line Status` and `Line Event`. If you need more information you would need to just concatenate `Header ID` and `Line ID` and use that with `MATCH(F:F,N:N,0)` to get the corresponding row number in P1 as reslut. With `=Index` you can use that row number to do further investigations on that rows.

[image]

Formulas:

- Column F: `=A:A & "-" & C:C`
- Column G: `=IFERROR(MATCH(F:F,P:P,0),"")`
- Column H: `=IF(G:G<>"",IF(INDEX(N:N,G:G)=D:D,"same","different"),"")`
- Column I: `=IF(G:G<>"",IF(INDEX(O:O,G:G)=E:E,"same","different"),"")`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. These steps were helpful for my task. :)